# How to seperate Unit Testing from main program in C++?

Tags: c++, testing

I am currently working on a C++ project and want to test my methods by myself. However, I would like the test them separated from the main loop of the program.

Here is a simplified code. In main.cpp;

```
int main() {

Numbers A(7.4) ;
Numbers B(6.6) ;

 cout << A.DoCalc(B);
```

}

In the Test.cpp file ;

```
    void TestDoCalc(Numbers &First, Numbers &Second, float &ExpectedResult){

    assert (First.DoCalc(Second) == ExpectedResult);
}

int main (){

    Numbers TestNumber1(2);
    Numbers TestNumber2(3);
    float ExpectedValue = 5 ;
    TestDoCalc(TestNumber1,TestNumber2,ExpectedValue);

    return 0;
}
```

Because there are multiple main loops, the compiler gives an error. How can I separately test my method so that the main loop of test.cpp will be run when only it is needed.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You might build them as two separate executable: one  is your application itself, another one is the unit test application you can run independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional compilation.

```
#ifdef TEST

int main (){

    Numbers TestNumber1(2);
    Numbers TestNumber2(3);
    float ExpectedValue = 5 ;
    TestDoCalc(TestNumber1,TestNumber2,ExpectedValue);

    return 0;
}

#else

int main() {
    Numbers A(7.4) ;
    Numbers B(6.6) ;

    cout << A.DoCalc(B);
}

#endif
```

Then define `-DTEST` (or your compiler's equivalent) to come up with the test executable, and the "normal" `main()` if `TEST` is not defined.

Even better, put each class, and `main()`, into individual source files. (Not a bad idea on general principles.) Then you can compile each source file into an object file, and link them together -- while at the same time, have *each* class source file come with its own `#ifdef TEST` / `main()` / `#endif` so you can compile each class implementation into its own testdriver.

Eventually, though, you should probably look into using a proper test framework like [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/), and have your test driver code separate from the class implementations -- non-trivial class implementations tend to get pretty long *without* having the test code in there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort on answering my question and wide explanation. May I ask how about if I want to test in another file? As indicated, in test.cpp

Comment: This is pretty basic C++ source code management. You put your test drivers in test.cpp, include the header that declares the class you're going to test, and call its member functions, checking the results...?!?